# Error to deploy in Heroku :es is not a valid locale

Tags: heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have the next error and I don't know how to resolve, I'm using rails 4.1 and ruby 2.1.3
the problem is with my locale file, I have app with portuguese language for default and I translate all the file necessaries, and in my local is right no problem but when do

**heroku run rake db:migrate**

**I have the next error:**

> Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.5369 rake
>   aborted! I18n::InvalidLocale: :es is not a valid locale
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0.beta1/lib/i18n.rb:284:in
>   `enforce_available_locales!'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0.beta1/lib/i18n/config.rb:34:in`
>   default_locale='
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0.beta1/lib/i18n.rb:35:in
>   `default_locale=' /app/config/environments/production.rb:75:in`block
>   in '

**I have a locale file and is :**

> I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}')]
>   I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**',
>   '*.{rb,yml}')]
>
> I18n.available_locales = Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales',
>   '*.{yml}')].collect {|l| locale = l.scan(/.+/(..).yml/)[0];
>   locale[0].to_sym unless locale.nil?}.delete_if {|locale| locale.nil?}
>
> I18n.default_locale = [:en, :es] I18n.config.enforce_available_locales
>   = true

**also in production.rb have :**

> I18n.default_locale = :es

I try all the options possibles but I don't have solution
Thanks for the time !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the solution for this problem is really easy and you need add in your application.rb this code:

> I18n.enforce_available_locales = false

Regards !